# Drupal - redirection after language change

Tags: drupal, redirect

I want to redirect users to the homepage when the change the language on my Drupal website.
Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should store in session current language of user, then if it changed, redirect to front page, then set to this session changed language.
In your template.php:

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page templates.
 *
 * @param $vars
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 * @param $hook
 *   The name of the template being rendered ("page" in this case.)
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  global $language;
  $currentlanguage = isset($_SESSION['currentlanguage']) ? $_SESSION['currentlanguage'] : $language->language;
  if ($language->language != $currentlanguage) {
    drupal_goto(url().'/'.$language->language); //goto current language version, if you use http://SITEURL/{languagecode} version, otherwise change it to appropriate.
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this code, and where do I set the session? I'm pretty new with Drupal. Sorry to be a newb.

Comment: Put the code in your theme's template.php file. Be sure to swap out "THEMENAME" in the snippet above with the name of your theme (or "phptemplate").

Comment: Also check that  THEMENAME_preprocess_page function exists there (of course change THEMENAME to your theme name). If it's there, just add code into this...

Comment: I added the code and nothing is happening.I also tried changing it to add the language to the session if it isn't set like this:
`code`
function salamanderskins_preprocess_page($vars, $hook) {
  global $language;
  $currentlanguage = isset($_SESSION['currentlanguage']) ? $_SESSION['currentlanguage'] : $language->language;
  if ($language->language != $currentlanguage) { 
    drupal_goto(url().'/'.$language->language); //goto current language version, if you use http://SITEURL/{languagecode} version, otherwise change it to appropriate.
  }
  $_SESSION['currentlanguage'] = $language->language;
}

Comment: `drupal_goto()` won't accept the language code (D7).

Comment: Wtower - check you language settings, read comment for drupal_goto please

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 6 write in template.php:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  global $language;
  $previouselanguage = isset($_SESSION['previouselanguage']) ? $_SESSION['previouselanguage'] : $language->language;
  $_SESSION['previouselanguage'] = $language->language;
  if ($language->language != $previouselanguage) {
    drupal_goto('');
  }
}
```